Solana Anchor Program: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')"
I'm trying to call a simple hello_world method from my Solana Anchor program, but I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')
    at .../node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/index.js:35:100

Here’s my JavaScript code:
import { Program, AnchorProvider, setProvider } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { PublicKey, Connection, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import bs58 from 'bs58';
import idl from './operator.json';

const connection = new Connection("http://127.0.0.1:8899"); // Localnet
const scionx = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode("my_secret_key"));

const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, scionx, { commitment: "confirmed" });
setProvider(provider);

const programID = new PublicKey("CMjNnp9yvMUqKJF2jB6E5HHpktwhm1ax9rHzh5risdNK");
const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);

const tx = await program.methods.helloWorld().accounts({
  user: scionx.publicKey
}).rpc();

console.log("Transaction signature:", tx);

Here’s the relevant part of my Rust contract:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[program]
pub mod operator {
    pub fn hello_world(_ctx: Context<HelloWorld>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Hello, World!");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct HelloWorld<'info> {
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

The program deploys fine, but I get the error when trying to call hello_world. Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks!

new Program(idl, programID, provider);  

===>
new Program(idl, provider);

The third parameter of Program should be a Coder, you passed your provider as a Coder.

this line
.../node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/index.js:35:100

has this code:
  const ixItem = instruction_js_1.default.build(idlIx, (ixName, ix) => coder.instruction.encode(ixName, ix), programId);

that means coder.instruction undefined.
upon checking docs
import { Idl, Coder } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";

import { SplMemoAccountsCoder } from "./accounts";
import { SplMemoEventsCoder } from "./events";
import { SplMemoInstructionCoder } from "./instructions";
import { SplMemoTypesCoder } from "./types";


export class SplMemoCoder implements Coder {
  readonly accounts: SplMemoAccountsCoder;
  readonly events: SplMemoEventsCoder;
  readonly instruction: SplMemoInstructionCoder;
  readonly types: SplMemoTypesCoder;

  constructor(idl: Idl) {
    this.accounts = new SplMemoAccountsCoder(idl);
    this.events = new SplMemoEventsCoder(idl);
    this.instruction = new SplMemoInstructionCoder(idl);
    this.types = new SplMemoTypesCoder(idl);
  }
}

you may not not be using correct idl

At first, second parameter for AnchorProvider is Wallet type, so replace like below.
 const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, scionx, { commitment: "confirmed" });

=>
 const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, new Wallet(scionx), { commitment: "confirmed" });

Second, Program has only two parameters and idl contains programid, so replace like below.
 const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);

=>
const program = new Program(idle as Idl, provider);

In a nutshell, this is full code for your case.
import { Program, AnchorProvider, setProvider, Wallet, Idl } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { Connection, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import idle from "../target/idl/test.json";

describe("test", async () => {

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const secretkey=[];//"your secret key arrry";
    const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com"); // Devnet
    const scionx = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secretkey));
    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, new Wallet(scionx), { commitment: "confirmed" });
    setProvider(provider);
    const program = new Program(idle as Idl, provider);
    const tx = await program.methods.helloWorld().accounts({
      user: scionx.publicKey
    }).rpc();

    console.log("Transaction signature:", tx);
  });

});
